# Optaplanner; How to use benchmark in Optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I want to use the optaplanner benchmark in order to compare between the solvers I used.

Is there a video explaining this issue because I'm confused using the docs, and I tried to implement what's written in the docs but it seems I missed something.

send me the video url if it exists.

Comment: There is a video. Go to optaplanner.org -> learn -> video's. There's also a chapter about it in the docs.

Comment: thanks for this quick response